# Wordpress php sqlite can't connect to .db

Tags: php, wordpress, sqlite

I am trying to connect to sqlite 3 .db.

`$db = new SQLite3('path/to/db.db');`

This gives me `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file`. Does it have something to do with php.ini? I read that i need to change permissions or something but didn't manage to do that. Also I am developing a web with Wordpress. Maybe I need to install sqlite or something, but how? Thanks.

Comment: are you using an extension to support sqlite? Wordpress doesn't support anything except mysql - there's a sqlite extension, but it's a bit hacky

Comment: WordPress, of course, uses MySQL, not SQLite. You may wish to [edit] your question to explain better what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do have .db file which is SQLite and I want to open it with php and edit and so on. I am not using extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress only supports MySQL.
There's an extension that supposedly supports Sqlite, but I've not personally used it, nor would I - https://wordpress.org/plugins/sqlite-integration/

Sometimes, just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Just use mysql?! What's wrong with using the (only) supported database if you're wanting to use wordpress?

Comment: I am not a lot experienced with all this php sqlite or mysql. I just want to edit .db file which is SQLite format 3. Can I do it with mysql?

Comment: Wordpress only supports mysql. It's easy to learn, there's loads of tutorials. Trying to hack it to use sqlite is a recipe for disaster imo.